# Botão para encerrar app

Tags: html, swift-3

Estou desenvolvendo um exemplo de app para Iphone usando o Xcode com Swift 3.0.
Necessito colocar um botão que ao ser clicado fecha todo o aplicativo.
Não consegui identificar nenhum evento ou função que faça isso.

Answer (score 0):

Existe um método para "sair" da aplicação:

```
exit(0)
```

**UPDATE**

Quotando a resposta de [Jeff Wolski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491466/call-exit0-in-iphone-app) (traduzida para português):

Segundo o Human User Guidelines da Apple...

> ## Não encerre a aplicação pelo código
>
> Nunca encerre um aplicativo iOS pelo código, pois seus usuários tendem
>   a interpretar isso como um crash. Todavia, se alguma circunstância
>   externa impede que sua aplicação funcione como deveria, você deve
>   informar ao usuário sobre esta situação e explicar o que ele pode
>   fazer quanto à isso. [...]

### Se, mesmo assim, você quer encerrar sua aplicação...

Em `C`, `exit(0)` irá interromper a execução da aplicação subitamente ("0" é o *status conde* que diz que o encerramento ocorreu com sucesso). Isso significa que nenhum método de *delegate* ou algoritmo de exceção será chamado. Logo, se a sua meta for ter certeza que algum código seja chamado antes de encerrar a aplicação, mesmo que forçado, talvez exista uma maneira melhor de fazer isso. No seu `AppDelegate`, implemente um método customizado como: `-(void)applicaitonIsgoingAway`. Chame este método dentro de onde você quer encerrar a aplicação:

- `applicationWillTerminate`
- `applicaitonDidEnterBackground`
- `onUncaughtException`

Comment: Tem alguma documentação oficial que trata deste método? Se sim, seria legal você colocar o link da mesma na resposta para servir de referência e material de estudo.

Comment: Usei uma resposta em inglês para embasar a resposta aqui.